# Запись и вывод куки в js

Tags: javascript, cookie

Как можно записать в куки значения location_name & location_id?
А потом проверять, если куки не пустой, выводить значения куки вывести в инпуты

```
$('.region-link').on('click',function(){
            var self = $(this);
            var location_name = self.data('name');
            var location_id = self.data('id');

        $(".location-input").val(location_name);
        $(".location-id-input").val(location_id);
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
    })

<input class="location-input" type="text" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myModal">
<input class="location-id-input" type="hidden" name="id_reg" >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

//сохранить
var location_name = $(".location-input").val();
setCookie('location_name', location_name, 365);

//прочитать
var location_name = getCookie('getCookie');
if (location_name != '')
{
    $(".location-input").val(location_name);
}
```